# Manually select multiple items in ListView

Tags: windows, xaml, visual-c++, c++-cx

I've created a ListView in my XAML file and set the SelectionMode to "Extended". I'd like to write a method that manually sets the selection on this list view.

The following works set set the selection for one item.

`MyListView->SelectedItem = SomeObject;`

`SelectedIndex` works just as well.

How do I set the selection for multiple items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your ListView's `SelectionMode` is "Multiple", and then you can just append to the SelectedItems collection on ListView.

This thread also includes a WPF example where you can use databinding/MVVM to accomplish the same goals (assuming your individual ListViewItems are bindable): http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/2418b2a1-6fbd-4820-b18f-e693111debbb

Note that the SelectedItems collection compares to the ItemsSource collection typically by object instance identity.  So, for example, this code will not cause the items to be selected:

```
auto v = ref new Vector<Object^>();
MyListView->ItemsSource = v;

Object^ o1 = "abc";
Object^ o2 = "def";
Object^ o3 = "ghi";

v->Append(o1);
v->Append(o2);
v->Append(o3);

MyListView->SelectedItems->Append("abc"); //"abc" is a distinct new string object
MyListView->SelectedItems->Append("ghi");
```

But changing the last two lines to this, will cause the items to become selected:

```
MyListView->SelectedItems->Append(o1);  //o1 is the same object found in ItemsSource
MyListView->SelectedItems->Append(o3);
```

Comment: Embarrassingly enough, I'm pretty sure I was trying to do this after I had set my SelectionMode to "Single". It works great now.